# C# Global Object

Tags: c#, oop, object, global

I am building a program for my course in which i need global objects as i intend to have the object accessible from many forms and edited also. Before saying just use global variables i cant the specs state for use of OOP.

my latest attempt to fix this is using a public class but this gave a protection error problem

Code:

Form1.cs (forgot to rename and not re doing all the code and design)

```
public class ObjectsGlobal
{
    Bays bay1 = new Bays();
    Bays bay10 = new Bays();
}
```

frmInput.cs

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( 1 == Convert.ToInt32(nudBayNum))
        {
           ObjectsGlobal.bay1.CarMake = txtMake.Text;
        }
    }
```

any ideas are welcome at this point

Comment: May I suggest reading [ask].

Comment: If you're curious about the downvotes from members A) this sounds like homework help, B) "NEED HELP ASAP" doesn't start you off on the right footing.

Comment: `bay1` and `bay10` access modifiers would not allow set/get from outside of the class

Comment: Read up on the Singleton pattern.

Comment: @New Terren as it states in the question it is for help on a piece of course work and the NEED HELP ASAP is me just being in patient tbh

Comment: Crap. Daniel's right.... And worse, I answered it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
public static class ObjectsGlobal
{
    public static Bays bay1 = new Bays();
    public static bay10 = new Bays();
}
```

Also, as recommended in a comment I have now read, take a look at the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).